# Do the ideas of Bloch wavefunction and Bragg scattering of electrons which apply to crystals also apply to liquid Mercury?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, metals, braggs-law, amorphous-solids

Do the ideas of Bloch wavefunction and Bragg scattering of electrons which apply to crystals also apply to liquid Mercury ?
Why is it that electrons in the liquid are not localised by the disordered positions of the mercury ions ?

Comment: Do you think that delocalization is due to the periodic structure? What about delocalization in a covalent molecule?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the applicability of [Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem)

> a Bloch-wave description applies more generally to any wave-like phenomenon in a *periodic* medium.

italics mine

[Mercury is  a liquid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)) at room temperatures thus has no lattice structure to have a Bloch's  wave function. It forms crystals when it freezes, so then it could apply, as with all lattices.

The same is true for [Bragg scattering](http://kinemage.biochem.duke.edu/teaching/bch291/pdfs/05.bragg) , it applies only in the crystal  phase.

> Why is it that electrons in the liquid are not localised by the disordered positions of the mercury ions ?

This is a question that you could ask for any liquid  [, water as an example](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/phase.html), and the answer is  the kinetic energy  (due to temperature) of the molecules forming the liquid does not allow to bond into a solid structure, and form *regular lattices*, to have periodic space solutions for the behavior of electrons and ions.

Comment: So is it correct that the metallic nature of conduction in mercury are not described in terms of Bloch electrons ?

Comment: of liquid mercury, yes. A different model is need to account for the fluidity and lack of periodicity.

Answer (score 0):

Disorder does not necessarily mean insulation and order does not imply conduction. For example, solid Si is a semiconductor and liquid Si a metal. Amorphous Si has no band gap and is a semiconductor.

The Hubbard model explains when electrons are localised, as in insulators and semiconductors, or delocalized, as in metals. Consider a lattice with one valence electron per site. The hopping matrix element t is the hamiltonian matrix element between two states with an electron displaced between nearest neighbors. The on-site repulsion U is the energy required for two electrons to be at the same site. If t dominates the electrons are delocalised, if U dominates they are localised.